# is PBKDF2 reversible?

Tags: pbkdf-2

Given an AES key that is wrapped using another AES key, the second one being generated using PBKDF2, and given that I know the wrapped key: can I derive the passphrase that went into the PBKDF2? (asking for a friend)

Comment: this could be about the key wrapping, rather than about PBKDF2 itself. please correct me if the question is wrong.

Comment: also, i AM using a salt.

Comment: whoever downvoted this question - it would be nice to know what i did wrong (so i can avoid it next time)

Comment: PBKDF2 is so obviously non-reversible that your friend shouldn't even be bothering you to ask it for him. This question is therefore showing no effort from either you or your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PBKDF2 is not reversible using any semi-safe underlying hash function, including for instance SHA1 or even MD5.

Comment: How can you affirm such? Are you an NSA-operative?

Comment: How can you affirm anything? Maybe P=NP? I am confident there are no publicly known methods to find a PBKDF2 preimage. I would be shocked if the nsa can(They may have dedicated hardware with a speedup of a few order of magnitudes, but that is not it).